# Create list from each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looping through elements using jQuery like this:

```
$(".myelement").each(function() {
  $element = $(this).closest(".panel").attr("id");
  console.log($element);
});
```

This is working correctly and I am seeing each of the elements it finds in my console log.  I am now trying to get a string containing each element that looks like this:

```
#element1, #element2, #element3
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Does anybody have an example they can point me at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map()` to build an array of the `id` then `join()` it, something like this:

```
var ids = $(".myelement").map(function() {
  return '#' + $(this).closest(".panel").prop("id");
}).get().join(', ');

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, map looks more appropriate than each. The returned list is missing the # that my each function returns though, any way to add that back in to each element returned?

Comment: Ah yes, you can concatenate it to the string you return, eg `return '#' + $(this).closest....`

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Reading up on map now to make sure I have a full understanding of what is going on

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array to store them by adding the `#` in every iteration, then after the loop end join them using `join()` method like :

```js
var ids = [];

$(".myelement").each(function() {
  ids.push('#' + $(this).closest(".panel").attr("id"));
});

console.log(ids.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1" class="panel">
  <span class="myelement">My element 1</span>
</div>
<div id="element2" class="panel">
  <span class="myelement">My element 2</span>
</div>
<div id="element3" class="panel">
  <span class="myelement">My element 3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

> The `.map()` method is particularly useful for getting or setting the value of a collection of elements.
>
> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call `.get()` on the result to work with a basic array.

You can use `map()`, `get()` and `join()`
in the following way:

```
var $element = $(".myelement").map(function(){
  return $(this).closest(".panel").attr("id"); 
}).get().join(', ');
console.log($element);
```